# how to filter on a private data value using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to filter on a private data value using jquery?

Example of the content of level_1_File, I only want to display a P element with the data-test_name of value level_1

```
   <p data-test_name="level_1"> Level 1 test results have passed </p> 
   <p data-test_name="level_2"> Level 1 test results have passed </p>
   <p data-test_name="level_3"> Level 1 test results have passed </p>
   <p data-test_name="level_4"> Level 1 test results have passed </p>



            $.get(level_1_File, function(data)
            {
                  $.each($(data), function(index, value))
                  {
                        alert($(value).html());
                  }

            });
```

This works but I only need the P element that has a data-test_name of value level_1, how do I filter for only this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each($(data), function(index, value)) {
  var $p = $(value);
  if ($p.data("test_name") == "level_1") {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(data).filter('p[data-test_name=​​level_1]');
```

will give you the give you the  P element that has a data-test_name of value level_1